# Combine text to a url in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Just started exploring `JQuery` and I came up with this code:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#submitButton').on('click', function () {
                                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://localhost:51091/getplayercomps/' + '$("#txtConfigKey").val()',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    data: '',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success: function (responseData, textStatus) {
                        alert(responseData);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

However, I do not know how to combine a `text` to `Url`.
That is,

`url: 'http://localhost:51091/getplayer/' + '$("#txtIdKey").val()',`

This seems not working.

JQuery sends the Url like this:

`http://localhost:51091/getplayer/$("#txtIdKey").val()` instead of the actual value being appended.

Any ideas what is the correct way to combine a textbox value to the `url` and invoke it ?

Comment: remove starting `'` and ending `'` from $("#txtIdKey").val() and you should be fine. It should be like `url: 'http://localhost:51091/getplayer/' + $("#txtIdKey").val(),`

Comment: @nikhiln Satpal: Thank you. It solved the issue. Please post as answer so that I will accept the same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove starting `'` and ending `'` from `$("#txtIdKey").val()` and it would work.

It should be like: `url: 'http://localhost:51091/getplayer/' + $("#txtIdKey").val(),`